# Outlook Flag Completed date format in excel

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am writing a macro in excel to export outlook emails to excel. The code works fine but the date format of 'Flag Completed Date' field changes when the data is exported to excel.

In outlook the format is "dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm" (Example: 21 January 2015 12:42).
When the emails are exported to excel, the format of this field changes to 21 January 2015 00:00

There are other date fields, their formats are correctly showing up in excel. Only this field is having the format issue.

Please help!

Thank you!
KSP

Here is the code that I am using:

```
Sub InboxToExcel()

    Dim objOL As Outlook.Application
    Dim objNS As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim objInbox As Outlook.Folder
    Dim objTable As Outlook.Table
    Dim objRow As Outlook.Row
    Dim objMsg As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim objWB As Excel.Workbook
    Dim objWS As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim objRange As Excel.Range
    Dim strFind As String
    Dim strProps As String
    Dim arr() As String
    Dim val As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim intRow As Integer

    strProps = _
      "SenderName,To,Subject,SentOn,ReadReceiptRequested"
    Set objOL = Application
    Set objNS = objOL.Session
    Set objInbox = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set objTable = objInbox.GetTable

    Set objWB = GetExcelWB()
    Set objWS = objWB.Sheets(1)
    objWS.Name = "Inbox"
    arr = Split(strProps, ",")
    intRow = 1
    For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
        objWS.Cells(intRow, i + 1) = arr(i)
        objTable.Columns.Add arr(i)
    Next
    Set objRange = objWS.Range _
                   (objWS.Cells(1, 1), objWS.Cells(1, i + 1))
    objRange.Font.Bold = True
    Do Until objTable.EndOfTable
        intRow = intRow + 1
        Set objRow = objTable.GetNextRow
        For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
            val = objRow(arr(i))
        Select Case VarType(val)
           Case vbDate
                val = DateToExcel(val)
           Case vbBoolean
                val = YesNoToString(val)
        End Select
            objWS.Cells(intRow, i + 1) = val
        Next
    Loop
    For i = 1 To (UBound(arr) + 1)
        objWS.Columns(i).EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Next
    objWS.Application.Visible = True
    objWS.Activate
    Set objOL = Nothing
    Set objNS = Nothing
    Set objRow = Nothing
    Set objWB = Nothing
    Set objWS = Nothing
    Set objRange = Nothing
End Sub

Function DateToExcel(propVal)
    Dim dteDate 'As Date
    If IsDate(propVal) Then
        dteDate = CDate(propVal)
        If dteDate = #1/1/4501# Then
            DateToExcel = Null
        Else
            DateToExcel = dteDate
        End If
    End If
End Function
Function YesNoToString(propVal)
    If propVal = "True" Then
        YesNoToString = "Yes"
    Else
        YesNoToString = "No"
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: It looks like you need to change the cell format or format the string you wrote to the cell in Excel. What code do you use?

Comment: Hi Eugene,I have added code for your reference.

Comment: Eugene, I have tried formatting cell in excel but it still shows 00:00 time. Looks like macro is not picking up time from the outlook field, it is picking only date

Comment: Try to debug the code and see what happens under the hood.

Comment: I have debug the code. It is only picking date but not time from the field value.Rest of the date fields are fine.

Comment: I am seeing the date with the time.  are you importing this into an existing sheet or a new sheet?  try a new sheet.